# Create a user-defined Parcelable object and implement functionality

Tags: java, android, parcelable

new to android programming. I have 2 objects that must be Parcelable called Book and Author. I am fairly certain I prepared them correctly. I was hoping for some help with:

- Creating a Book
- sending them to a new activity

  ```
  public class Book implements Parcelable {

  public int id;
  public String title;
  public ArrayList<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>();
  public int Aflags;
  public String isbn;
  public String price;

  @Override
  public int describeContents() {
      return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
      out.writeInt(id);
      out.writeString(title);
      out.writeTypedList(authors);
      out.writeString(isbn);
      out.writeString(price);
  }

  private Book(Parcel in) {
      id = in.readInt();
      title = in.readString();
      in.readTypedList(authors, Author.CREATOR);
      isbn = in.readString();
      price = in.readString();
  }


  public static final Parcelable.Creator<Book> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Book>() {
      public Book createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
          return new Book(in);
      }
      public Book[] newArray(int size) {
          return new Book[size];
      }
  };

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
      return title + " Price: " + price;
  }

   }
  ```

  Now Author:

  ```
  public class Author implements Parcelable {

  // TODO Modify this to implement the Parcelable interface.
  // I think I was able to accomplish this
  // NOTE: middleInitial may be NULL!

  public String firstName;

  public String middleInitial;

  public String lastName;

  @Override
  public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
      out.writeString(firstName);
      if (middleInitial.length() == 0)
          out.writeString(middleInitial);
      out.writeString(lastName);
  }

  private Author(Parcel in)
  {
      firstName = in.readString();
      if (in.dataSize() > 2)
          middleInitial = in.readString();
      lastName = in.readString();
  }

  public static final Parcelable.Creator<Author> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Author>() {
      public Author createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
          return new Author(in);
      }

      public Author[] newArray(int size) {
          return new Author[size];
      }
  };

  @Override
  public int describeContents() {
      return 0;
  }


    }
  ```

I don't know why I'm stumped but I can't find out how to implement my Parcel to make the book and go any further. This is the activity that is trying to make the book then send it to another activity:

```
public class AddBookActivity extends Activity {

// Use this as the key to return the book details as a Parcelable extra in the result intent.
public static final String BOOK_RESULT_KEY = "book_result";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_book);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    // COMPLETED TODO provider SEARCH and CANCEL options
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    // TODO
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.search:
    // SEARCH: return the book details to the BookStore activity
        this.searchBook();
    return true;
    case R.id.cancel:
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Cancel Search")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel your search?")
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                AddBookActivity.this.finish();
            }
         })
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                // do nothing
            }
         })
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
         .show();
    // CANCEL: cancel the search request
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public Book searchBook(){
    /*
     * Book object with the search criteria and return that.
    */
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_title);
    String title = editText.getText().toString();
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_author);
    String author = editText.getText().toString();
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_isbn);
    int isbn = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
    Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
    p.writeInt(isbn);
    p.writeString(title);
    p.writeString(author);
    p.writeString(editText.getText().toString());
    p.writeString("$15.00");
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: what you want to do with last part of your code? pass data between two Activity?

Comment: After I have the book I'd send it to a new activity and it would be added to a list of books that have already been created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to send the parcelable object to a new Activity through the use of an Intent, it should be as simple as calling intentobject.putExtra("key", parcelableobject). Android will handle the rest for you because your object implements the Parcelable interface.

Comment: Well I first need to get the object created. As in I need to make that Parcel p into a book object. Then I want to send the book object (which implements parcelable)

Comment: The ideal way to do that would probably be to have a normal constructor in your book class that initializes the necessary variables in the class. Parcels are not meant as a stand-in for object construction.

Comment: Omg you just made it click

Answer (score 1):

for sending data use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("listOfBook", bookList); // sending list
intent.putExtra("objOfBook", bookObj);  // sending obj
startActivity(intent);
```

and for getting that:

```
ArrayList<Book> myList = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("listOfBook"); // getting list
Book bookObj = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("objOfBook"); // getting obj
```

edit following function with my code:

```
public Book searchBook(){
    /*
     * Book object with the search criteria and return that.
    */
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_title);
    String title = editText.getText().toString();
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_author);
    String author = editText.getText().toString();
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_isbn);
    int isbn = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
    Book b = new Book();
    b.SetIsbn(isbn);
    b.SetTitle(title);
    b.SetAuthor(author);
    b.SetPrice("$15.00")
    // i don't know what for is last line
    return b;
}
```

Comment: you don't need parcel obj, just create one object of Book and send that , see my answer to send that

Comment: I added my activity java file. I think I need to use the BOOK_RESULT_KEY to help but I'm not sure. hope this helps you help me more.

Comment: see my Edit, what you need Parcelable at all? i dont see anywhere that you send Book object